# Perfect continuous tense with the verb "have"

Tags: tenses

What is the difference between

> Do you have a good time?

and

> Are you having a good time?

Thanks

Comment: None I can think of - the second sounds better since it emphasizes the continuation of the good time

Answer (score 3):

'*Do you have a good time?*' would imply having a good time is a regular action. If a person enjoys regularly, than he would answer affirmitively to this question.

As @EdwinAshworth says:

> 'Do you have a good time?' sounds distinctly unidiomatic without contextualisation such as: 'We often go to the zoo in Stackton Trestle.' - 'Do you have a good time?'

Another instance could be:

> "Do you have a good time at school?"

since going to school *is* a regular action.

---

'*Are you having a good time?*' conveys that you are asking if the person is *currently* having a good time. The person may be living in hell, but suppose he goes to a party and you ask him this while he is enjoying, the answer would be yes.

Comment: Yes - and _'Do you have a good time?'_ sounds distinctly unidiomatic without contextualisation such as: 'We often go to the zoo in Stackton Trestle.' - 'Do you have a good time?'

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll add that too :)